# $K$ is Bounded Operator in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K:L^2([0,2\pi])\to L^2([0,2\pi])$ and $\displaystyle Kf(t)=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(t-s)}f(s)ds$

Show that:
a) $K$ is bounded.
b) Calculate $K^*$.

Any help and comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just Cauchy-Schwarz:

> $$c\int\left|\int e^{i(s-t)}f(s)\,ds\right|\,dt\le \lVert f(s)\rVert_{L^2}$$

(the $c$ is just the normalization constant)

Taking the supremum over all $L^2$ norm $1$ functions says the norm is at most $1$, and with $f(s) = e^{-is}$ we see the norm is exactly $1$ as usual.